# ftp_connect() is not working on production

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp

**Localhost:**

In php application `ftp_connect("000.000.0.00")` is working fine, means when I am trying to browse a file from local system and uploading this file on FTPit is working.

**Production Server:**
When I am deploying my PHP application on production and trying to get FTP connection by `ftp_connect("000.000.0.00")` is it not getting connected. it is returning FALSE.
please tell me how do I connect on FTP to upload my files through my PHP application.

```
<?php
$ftp_server="000.000.0.00";
$ftp_user_name="myftpuser";
$ftp_user_pass="myftppwd";

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result))
{
    echo "Connection Failed.";
}
else
{
    echo "Connected.";
}
?>
```

Comment: is the files you want to upload are on the same production server you are using

Comment: Is your prod server a dedicated ? If not, it may come from your server provider that disallow any other exit than HTTP port. Take a look at FAQ of your provider by anychance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `000.000.0.00` with your ftp server.

Refer here: [ftp_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php)

Comment: "000.000.0.00" is for showing you.i have put actual ftpserver url name without http:// and any trailing slashes (like "abc.com") in ftp_connect("abc.com"). it is working and getting connected by localhost but not connected by production server.